# Dataframe concat value columns of multiple tables with matching index columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, multiple-columns

I have following tables in a pandas dataframe:

| ID1 | ID2 | Value1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data1 | Data2 | Data11 |

| ID1 | ID2 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data1 | Data2 | Data12 |

| ID1 | ID2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data1 | Data2 | Data13 |

My aim is a table of form:

| ID1 | ID2 | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data1 | Data2 | Data11 | Data12 | Data13 |

What is the easiest way to do that with python?

Comment: Do you have three separate dataframes?

Comment: yes I have three seperate dataframes for each table. The aim-table should be in a new dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).groupby(['ID1', 'ID2'], as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
     ID1    ID2  Value1  Value2  Value3
0  Data1  Data2  Data11  Data12  Data13
```

Answer (score 2):

Perform multiple [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)s in a chain:

```
df1.merge(df2.merge(df3))

#      ID1    ID2  Value1  Value2  Value3
# 0  Data1  Data2  Data11  Data12  Data13
```

Or with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) syntax:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda L, R: L.merge(R, on=['ID1', 'ID2']), [df1, df2, df3])
```

Comment: lol. my answer: `reduce(lambda dfL, dfR: dfL.merge(dfR, on=['ID1', 'ID2']), [df1, df2, df3])`